# PHP MySQL syntax error, works ok in Sequel Pro

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of PHP code:

```
echo $sql;
echo "<P>";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
  echo $conn->error;
```

And it produces this result:

> select reknro, nimi, sukup, synt, isa, ema, kuvaus, kennelnimi from
>   skl_koirat k, skl_varit v where k.varikoodi = v.id and k.reknro in
>   (select distinct reknro from ttk_koira_sairaus where kysymys_id = 15
>   or kysymys_id = 16)
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'or kysymys_id = 16)' at line 1

When I copy-paste the sql command to Sequel Pro and execute it there, it produces an output and not an error. Why does PHP think there is an error?

(some background: the 'where' clause in inner select is created programatically by after the user has selected checkboxes in a form: if there is only one checkbox selected there is no 'or' in the 'where' clause and it works. If user selects more checkboxes, each is added to where clause with 'or', and as soon as there is a single 'or' the syntax error appears. The same happens if the conditions are combined with 'and')

Answer (score 0):

Try `kysymys_id IN (15, 16)`. Maybe that will work.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work (although I don't get why the original didn't work).

Comment: However, how do I change it if I need to use 'and' instead of 'or' (this too, is user selectable. So I need to get this working as well:

Comment: select reknro, nimi, sukup, synt, isa, ema, kuvaus, kennelnimi from skl_koirat k, skl_varit v where k.varikoodi = v.id and k.reknro in (select distinct reknro from ttk_koira_sairaus where kysymys_id = 15 and kysymys_id = 16)

Comment: Except `kysymys_id` cannot be `15 AND 16` at the same time

Comment: Heh, that's true ;-) I need to rework that SQL (the idea is to get all reknro's for which there exists both kysymys_id 15 AND kysymys_id 16)

Comment: Yes, it will return 0 records. Anyway, you should use in instead of or, because it works so much faster.

Comment: 'and' instead of 'or' in the original query also returns an error (while it shouldn't; it should always return empty result set). But since the query with 'and' is logically flawed anyways, it doesn't matter (to me)

Comment: what mysql version you are using?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7